# interactive gif linking to video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, coordinates

I'm making an interactive world map gif, using javascript and html5, here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>World Map</title>
    <body>
<p>Click on a clickable area of the map for more info.</p>
<img src ="worldmap.gif" width="576" height="307" alt="World Map" usemap="#worldmap">

<map name="worldmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="265,49,279,64" href="
```

but now I'm stuck, firstly i want to know how to link to a video within the html5 video tags, upon the clicking of the linked coordinates, and also how to set javascript parameters within this, such as swapping videos etc. I have the code to be able to do the swap with the videos once the link is clicked, and I have the code to do the coordinates, I just don't know how to put it together.

Thanks so much for you help, but want to keep it super simple using the method i've done and kind of understand (if it works) here is my super simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <title>World Map</title>
    <body>
<p>Click on a clickable area of the map for more info.</p>
<img src ="worldmap.gif" width="576" height="307" alt="World Map" usemap="#worldmap">

<map name="worldmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="265,49,279,64" <video src="ukanthem.mp4"></video>
</map>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

the map opens on the page, but the clickable area does not appear to be there?

UPDATE:
So the coordinates still don't work, there is no area to click
also the video's appear on the same page as my map, I would like them on a seperate page, any help? also the video's aren't recognised, it says "video cannot be found, may have been removed from the server. http 404"
    
     
    
        World Map

Click on a clickable area of the map for more info.

```
<map name="worldmap">

<area shape="rect" coords="265,49,279,64" onclick="playVideo()"> 
<video id="video1" class="true" autoplay controls width="420">
<source src="ukanthem.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="ukanthem.mp4" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<video id="video2" class=flase" width="420" controls>
<source src="beef.mp4">
</video>
<button id="hideButton" onclick="swap();">Switch</button>


<script>
var flag=true;
function swap() {
var myVideo1=document.getElementById("Video1");
var myVideo2=document.getElementById("video2");
flag=!flag;
video1.setAttribute("class", flag);
video2.setAttribute("class", !flag);
if (flag) {
    video2.pause();
    video1.play();
} else {
    video1.pause();
    video2.play();
}
}
</script>


</map>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Look at my code again please :)**

Ok super simple.

You can put an Onclick action to your area tag.

Like this.

```
<area .... onclick="playVideo()">
```

And for your HTML 5 video tag...

```
<video id="video1" width="420">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

And a Javascript to do things for you:
This part is for the normal HEAD HTML tag <-------

```
<script>
function playVideo() {
  var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 
  myVideo.play(); 
}
</script>
```

If you want it super easy this is super easy, and i havent used any jquery, or new stuff.  Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: What you need to do is to manage the different states the videos can be in, lets say if video1 is playing, and u pressed video2 link.  THen video 1 should stop and video 2 should play.  But its your site, im just guessing now :)  Usually im not a fan of this site, but if you want it super simple:  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp   try looking here.

Answer (score 0):

You need a video tag:

```
<video src="urlofvideo"></video>
```

You can use jQuery to bind the click events on the image map:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('area').bind('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

       //url of video
        var url = this.href;
       //Here your code to start the video 
       ...
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure i understood your question, but i made you this.  Its a map with cords on, this is without the old map method, but its with HTML, CSS and Jquery instead.

Sorry if i totally misunderstood, but its my shoot :)

```
<style type="text/css">
  .map_image { display: block; width: 1280px; height: 960px;  background-repeat: no-repeat; }
  .map_image .map_link { display: block; position: absolute; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; }
  .map_image #paris { width: 150px; height: 80px; top: 11px; left: 11px; border: 1px solid red; }
  .map_image #copenhagen { width: 150px; height: 80px; top: 40px; left: 177px; border: 1px solid yellow;}
</style>

 <div class="map_image" style="background-image: url('your_picture.jpg');">
   <a class="map_link" id="paris" title="google.com"></a>
   <a class="map_link" id="copenhagen" title=""></a>
 </div>

<script>
  $("#paris").click(function() {
    // play a video about paris
    alert("paris");
  });

  $("#copenhagen").click(function() {
    // play a video about paris
    alert("copenhagen");
  });
</script>
```